# $x_{n+1}=\{ x_n$ if n is odd and $x_n^2$ if n is even}. What is the limit of $\{x_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_1=\alpha$, where $|\alpha|<1$ is a real number. For $n=1,2,3...$ define $x_{n+1}=\{ x_n$ if n is odd and $x_n^2$ if  n is even}. What is the limit of $\{x_n\}$

From the recurring relation we are getting $x_1=x_2=\alpha$ ; $x_3=x_4=\alpha^2$;...

So $x_{2n}=\alpha^n \rightarrow 0$

The limit of sequence should be 0. My query is if the method of proof correct?

Comment: It won't quite be $x_{2n}=\alpha^n$, e.g. $x_6=\alpha^4$, but certainly it is some power of $\alpha$ which tends to $0$. I think you want to note that both $x_{2n}\to 0$ and $x_{2n+1}\to 0$ in order to deduce that $x_n\to 0$.

Comment: It seems that $x_{2n}=\alpha^{2^n}$. In any case, the limit is indeed $0$ y the choice of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

By induction, one can show that $x_{2n}=\alpha^{2^n}$.

- For $n=1$ it is true since $x_1=\alpha$ and $x_2=x^2_2=\alpha^{2^1}=\alpha^2$.
- Assume the expression holds for some $n$,$n\geq1$.  For $n+1$ we have
  $x_{2n+1}=x_{2n}=\alpha^{2^n}$ and so, $x_{2n+2}=x^{2}_{2n+1}=(\alpha^{2^n})^2=\alpha^{2^{n+1}}$.

---

If $|\alpha|<1$, then the limit of $x_n$ is indeed $0$.